# How can I use an emscripted .js library in a Web Worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker, emscripten

**I've compiled my program into a single `program.js` file, and within the worker, I call:**

```
importScripts('program.js');
Module.callMain();
```

**However, although `callMain` is executing, within that function invocation's stack I am getting the `Undefined is not a function` error.**

My hunch is that I haven't read some essential *emscripten* documentation, wiki, or sourcecode.

#### What I know:

- *emscripten* has bindings to work with workers, but only when there is an emscripted process on the main thread to use these bindings (see [emscripten.h](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/39f126fa1749377f653b25efd475a3a23b7a620c/system/include/emscripten/emscripten.h))
- In order to compile a task (within a library that runs on the main thread) to a worker, `emcc` needs special options passed *at compile time for that task* (see [settings.js](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/39f126fa1749377f653b25efd475a3a23b7a620c/src/settings.js))

#### What I surmise:

- There may be flags that I need to pass to let emcc know not to call functions on nonexistent objects, like `window`
- Having looked through the implementation of `/dev/tty`, which is linked to by `/dev/stdin`, and the implementation of `/dev/stdout`, I believe there may be output to the `console`, which I don't believe is supported in a worker

#### What I am asking:

- How can I use my library, a single js file, in a worker?

  - My library loads other files from a `program.data` file, if that makes a difference

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if I can add any details.

---

*Note: the code at top is simplified - it doesn't seem to be an error in syntax.*

#### Update:

- The stacktrace (`Error.stack`) only tells me that the error occured in `Module.callMain`. It does not tell me anything about the imported script that might be causing it. :(

Answer (score 3):

Emscripten output should run on a website, on a web worker, or in node, all without modifications. There might be some limitations (e.g. no canvas to render to in a worker), but otherwise it is just pure JS that can run in those three environments.

Does the exact same JS file that emscripten generated work outside of a worker?

If `callMain()` fails, check that your project has a `main()` function.

Comment: Should main need to be an exported function (`_main`)?

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after loading the js (by `importScripts()`) it may not be executed yet, hence you are not ready. You can ask Emscripten to call a callback for you when things are ready. You will have functions accessible via the variable `Module`.

```
var Module = {
    preRun:[],
    onRuntimeInitialized: function load_done_callback() {
        console.info("The Module is loaded and is accessible here", Module);
        console.inf("no need to call main() though", Module._main); // add "_" before your function names
    },
};

importScripts('program.js');
```

No need to call `callMain()` or `Module._main()`, it will be called for you. You may need to set `NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1` in compiler command line:

```
em++  \
  -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_main', '_myfunction1' , '_my_function2' ]" \
  -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 \
  -s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1 \
  program.cpp \
  -o ./program.js
```

Note that you don't need to compile as worker in this case where you use `importScripts()`.

Comment: I noticed that simply calling `importScripts()` without using the synchronous load callback `onRuntimeInitialized:` worked for me. But I am not sure if would be guaranteed to work.